# How a get creation time of uploaded file?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I have a java servlet via glassfish 5 with the functionality for upload a file, servlet has multipart config

```
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
... 
Part filePart = request.getPart("userfile");
Timestamp/Time createTime = filePart.mysticFunctionForGetCreationTImeFromPart(); // ???
```

How I can get a creation time of uploaded file?

Comment: yeap. Client upload file to me (server), and I want to get a creation time of uploaded file.

Comment: File sends from a browser... Maybe I can send it with a request header?...